# how to test libgdx admob on java application if emulator not working?

Tags: admob, libgdx

My emulator is not working fine simultaneously I want to test my "libgdx admob" code on my application.
Is there any way to test it on desktop application of libgdx?
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to test the admob code in the desktop version. There are some platform specific things that are not available on the desktop version. This includes the admob view and other Android specific dependencies. I recommend to either try to get the emulator up running, or to find some way to test on a phone. The best is probably to do both.

Comment: One more thing sir...
What change should i do in the androidmanifest.xml to run the libgdx admob code properly?

Comment: It depends on wether you add the admob view programmaticaly or via xml. In any case you should read the admob sdk instructions (with code samples) here: [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) For the code samples, make sure to switch the code window to android (default is on iOS). To do so click the Android label on top of the code (There's iOS, Android, Windows Phone 7). Please mark this answer as the right one, unless someone gives a different answer.

Comment: but i wanted to ask regarding the permissions we need to add in android manifest that will enable "ads viewing" on the test device.